# Notify a background download after a time

Tags: ios, iphone, nsnotificationcenter

In my app I need to update data after time, say 5 days, after 5 days when user uses the app, a downloading view will come and do the task.
I want to schedule some notification to trigger a download function after 5 days when the user use the app. I can do custom check of time, but I don't want to perform check on every applicationDidBecomeActive and see if the 5 days has passed. Is there any other clean way, of doing this. I was looking in NSNoticationCenter but I couldn't find any thing regarding this. Any other way of doing this

Comment: I think the best way you can do it is exactly as you suggested, take a time stamp the first time he downloads and every time the app opens compare to that, I think its quite a clean solution.

Comment: Use local notification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a UILocalNotification with a specific `fireDate`. Check the documentation at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Ain't localNotification on device level, I just want to queue a task after 5 days

Comment: Well. You want a "downloading view" to "come and do the task" after 5 days. You understand that no view can come, by surprise, without user's consent. Well, UILocalNotification will do just that: present a message to the user, and let him open your application which will do the task. Did you read the link I gave you? It's good to know about your tools, you know.

Comment: I have experience working with localNotificatinos and how these work, the things is my client doesn't want his users to get annoyed of app, Using LocalNotification will notify the user after every 5 days, so the user may get annoyed.

Comment: or may be the timestamp mechanism will be fine for this scenario

Comment: Your own words talk about a view. Don't expect to be able to display a view without user consent - at the cost of annoying them. If you don't really want to display a view, go edit your question so that we reader are not mislead, and then go read the "Background Fetch" paragraph at the excellent http://www.objc.io/issue-5/multitasking.html article: you'll learn how to schedule background downloads at specific times.

Comment: my view is just an iToast, but u point me in the right direction of schedule background downloads, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use UILocalNotification

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
localNotification.fireDate = futureDate; //Modify the date according to your logic 
localNotification.alertBody = @"Some Alert";
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

You have to calculate when the next download should happen and give that date in fireDate.

if your app is in background this method will be called.

```
application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
```

If it is in foreground this method will be called

```
application: didReceiveLocalNotification:
```

Put your condition of downloading your data there and after your action create another Localnotification and schedule it

if you don't want to use the Local Notification then keep a schedule date stored in NSSuserdefaults. When the user launches your app each time check with the date and time. Then do your stuff in that condition.It need not to be in applicationDidBecomeActive it can be in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. So that download will happen fresh when the user starts your app.

Comment: I have experience working with localNotificatinos and how these work, the things is my client doesn't want his users to get annoyed of app, Using LocalNotification will notify the user after every 5 days, so the user may get annoyed.

Comment: Ya i got it. Then the convenient way is a manual check on applicationDidFinishLaunching. I suggest you to check these downloads or updates when the user is launching his app fresh. User can launch your app after 5 or 6 or 7 days so if your condition exceeds 5 days then start your download.

Comment: then checking timeStamp mechanism will be fine in this scenario. I also suggested it in my question. I was looking if there is some scheduling task in iOS. But thanks